# Include contents of char array in flat binary file

Tags: c, assembly, embedded, inline-assembly, osdev

I am using flat binary files as external programs for my OS. When I compile them, like so:

```
gcc -Wall ctest.c -o ctest.bin -nostdlib -Wl,-Ttext=0x8000,-nostdlib -masm=intel
objcopy -O binary -j .text ctest.bin ctest
```

But doing this, the contents of the character array aren't put in the file. This is my code:

```
static volatile char string[4] = "Hi!\0";
static volatile char string2[15] = "Hello, World!\n\0";

int _start()
{
    asm("mov eax, [string]");
    asm("mov ebx, 0x00");
    asm("int 0x01");
    asm("mov eax, [string2]");
    asm("mov ebx, 0x00");
    asm("int 0x01");
    return 0;
}
```

and when I run objdump (I ran it on the elf, but I verified it had the same code as this):

```
00008000 <_start>:
8000:   55                      push   ebp
8001:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
8003:   a1 70 90 00 00          mov    eax,ds:0x9070
8008:   bb 00 00 00 00          mov    ebx,0x0
800d:   cd 01                   int    0x1
800f:   a1 74 90 00 00          mov    eax,ds:0x9074
8014:   bb 00 00 00 00          mov    ebx,0x0
8019:   cd 01                   int    0x1
801b:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
8020:   5d                      pop    ebp
8021:   c3                      ret
```

As you can see, the text is nowhere to be found. I was hoping it would do something like this: `string db "Hi!", 0` which I would do with nasm.

What should I do so it includes the characters in the output bin file without coding this in assembly?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Added some more useful tags

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Thanks, but would this really qualify as embedded? As this is running on a regular PC.

Comment: Yes, But I added so that can be noticed people working for embedded. I think they can also help you on this question :)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: doesn't that only examine files though? I cant find anywhere a way to create a binary with it.

Comment: What flag are you giving to objdump?

Answer (score 4):

A binary executable file is typically divided into sections. Your strings have simply been placed into a different section than the code. This makes sense, since the code should be read-only but the strings have been declared non-const and volatile.

Comment: Is there any way to force them into the same section (text I think) before/while doing the objcopy?

Comment: @farlepet: you could add a `-j .data` to the `objcopy` arguments to get the strings into the binary.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: When i do that, there is a 4000 byte gap between the text and the data sections, is there a way to remove that without doing it manually?

Comment: @farlepet, try just declaring the strings `const` and removing `volatile`. It's still up to the compiler where they go, but the chances they will be placed in the text section increases.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I tried that, but that doesn't include them in the .text section, and now when i use objcopy with -j .data, it doesn't add anything after the text section

Comment: @farlepet:  when you changed the declaration to const, the array moved to a yet a different section again (maybe .const or .rodata).  So you'd have to add another -j option to the command line.  You should read the manual for your linker.  There you'll learn how to specify in linker directive file where a section should be located and how to specify a custom section for your array with a pragma statement.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do it.
First I created a linker script like this (You can change `phys` to whatever address you want to load it at):

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary")
ENTRY(start)
phys = 0x8000;
SECTIONS
{
  .text phys : AT(phys) {
    code = .;
    *(.text)
    *(.rodata)
    . = ALIGN(0);
  }
  .data : AT(phys + (data - code))
  {
    data = .;
    *(.data)
    . = ALIGN(0);
  }
  .bss : AT(phys + (bss - code))
  {
    bss = .;
    *(.bss)
    . = ALIGN(0);
  }
  end = .;
}
```

Then compiled and linked the executable like this:

```
gcc -m32 -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -o exec.o exec.c
ld -T link.ld -melf_i386 -o exec.bin exec.o
```